# Castle Windsor Child Container Lifetime

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Under what conditions will windsor dispose/remove child containers if they are not explicitly removed from the parent container via parent.RemoveChildContainer(child)?  I assume they would live in the parent's child container collection indefinitely regardless of held references outside of parent.  Has anyone tested this or have some insight here?

Answer (score 0):

WindsorContainer implements IDisposable and a child container will be removed from its parent when it is disposed:

```
    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        Parent = null;
        childContainers.Clear();
        kernel.Dispose();
    }
```

When it is disposed is up to specific implementation. For example, if I create a child container every time I open a new form on a Winform application, I can dispose it when a form is closed. Another example is when I create a child container for every web request:

```
Component.For<IMyService>().UsingFactoryMethod(k =>
            {
                var childContainer = new WindsorContainer() { Parent = parentContainer };
                return new MyService(childContainer);

            }).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest;
```

MyService will also implement IDisposable:

```
public class MyService : IMyService, IDisposable
{
    public MyService(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
       ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Indeed how you use child container may be very different. I just wanted to share some experience :)

Comment: Yes, this is all true.  I was just curious if there was anything internal to the kernel that would auto dispose child containers that nothing else held a reference to.  I am fairly sure the answer is no but I wasn't sure if CW did any internal clean up for child containers that were no longer in use.